# Why the Maven surefire-report-plugin creates the error message "Character encoding ${outputEncoding} is not supported by this plattform"?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I have configured the maven surefire-report-plugin as well:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.17</version>
   <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${myPath}</outputDirectory>
        <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
       <execution>
            <id>create-surefire-report</id>
            <phase>test</phase>  
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>                   
    </executions>              
</plugin>
```

Here is the configuration of the Maven-surefire-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>                    
    </configuration>                
</plugin>
```

How can I solve this problem? What should be changed in this configuration?

Thanks !

Comment: You should take care that the versions of maven-surefire-plugin and maven-surefire-report-plugin are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove `<outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>` from `<configuration>`
2. Same level to `<reporting>` tag, define `<properties>` with `outputEncoding` like this

   ```
   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
   </properties>

   <reporting>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
              ...
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </reporting>
   ```

**Note**: this will work with `Maven 2.x` & `Maven 3.x`.

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for your point as I am not sure with `Maven 3.x`.!!

Comment: To be clear this has nothing to do with Maven 2/3 it is the jobs of the plugins which follow default guide lines in using such properties for encoding.

Comment: Is it right, that I don´t reference the created soureEndoing and outputEndcoding directly in the the config of the maven surefire report plugin?

Comment: @Marwief yes no need to put those setting directly in the config under surefire report plugin !!

Comment: but in the maven surefire plugin it is necessary, right?

Comment: @Marwief Regarding with `maven surefire plugin`, let it be as you configured in your post.

Comment: But I have the problem, that the error message "Character encoding ${outputEncoding} is not supported by this plattform?" is still visible. Whether I´m using propertie definitions or directly endong format in the plugin

Comment: @Marwief You used `${outputEncoding}` expression in other config/setting ?? How using `${project.reporting.outputEncoding}` instead ??